# MongoDB - single huge collection of raw data. Split or not?

Tags: mongodb

We collect and store instrumentation data from a large number of hosts. 
Our storage is MongoDB - several shards with replicas. Everything is stored in a single large collection.
Each document we insert is a time based observation with some attributes (measurements). The time stamp is the most important attribute because all queries are based on time at least. Documents are never updated, so it's a pure write-in-look-up model. Right now it works reasonably well with several billions of docs.

Now,

We want to grow a bit and hold up to 12 month of data which may amount to a scary trillion+ observations (documents).
I was wandering if dumping everything into a single monstrous collection is the best choice or there is a more intelligent way to go about it.
By more intelligent I mean - use less hardware while still providing fast inserts and (importantly) fast queries.
So I thought about splitting the large collection into smaller pieces hoping to gain memory on indexes, insertion and query speed.

I looked into shards, but sharding by the time stamp sounds like a bad idea because all writes will go into one node canceling the benefits of sharding.
The insert rates are pretty high, so we need sharding to work properly here.
I also thought about creating a new collection every month and then pick up a relevant collection for a user query.
Collections older than 12 month will be either dropped or archived.
There is also an option to create entirely new database every month and do similar rotation.
Other options? Or perhaps one large collection is **THE** option to grow real big?

Please share your experience and considerations in similar apps.

Comment: Are your queries range based on time?

Comment: Yes, the time is the major parameter in all queries. Additionally users may select other attributes. For example, "fetch me the stuff from last sunday of particular origin and having red color or when temperature is below zero".

Comment: @Dima Finally, what was your decision? Which way did you go?

Comment: @Bogdan Burim, I went for creating "partitions" to store smaller amount of data bound by the time span. In my case a "partition" holds few days of data. Partition is a separate database in my case, but using collection also would make sense.. I think I went for database because they are easier to drop when very large. Works well so far.

Comment: @Dima Thanks for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the use-case for your queries.

If it's something that could be aggregated, I would say do this through a scheduled map/reduce function and store the smaller data size in separate collection(s).

If everything should be in the same collection and all data should be queried at the same time to generate the desired results, then you need to go with Sharding. Then depending on the data size for your queries, you could go with an in memory map/reduce or even doing it at the application layer.

As yourself pointed out, Sharding based on time is a very bad idea. It makes all the writes going to one shard, so define your shard key. [MongoDB Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-internals/), has a very good explanation on this.

If you can elaborate more on your specific needs for the queries would be easier to suggest something.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The collection holds pure raw data - readings of some sensors. Each reading is a bunch of flat name-value pairs which makes one document. Queries can be done by any combination of attributes but time is always present and is the major index in the collection. We already use sharding spreading these observations by their origin. But the shear amount of the stuff makes me wonder if single collection is the right choice.

Comment: What are the types of queries you have? Could you aggregate the old records and for queries just use the aggregated values, or it needs to be calculated from scratch for every query?

Also how often you execute the queries?

Answer (score 2):

I think collection on monthly basis will help you to get some boost up but I was wondering why can not you use the hour field of your timestamp for sharding . You can add a column which will hold the HOUR part of time stamp and when you shard against it will be shared nicely as you have repeating hour daily basis. I have not tested it but thought it will may help you

Comment: actually when you mentioned "use the hour field of your timestamp for sharding" it ringed the bell.. I haven't thought about this. I was only looking at the absolute time as sharding key. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest to go ahead with single collection, as suggested by @Devesh hour based shard should be fine, Need to take care of the new ' hour Key ' while querying to get better performance.